# Serial communication with Velleman relais card

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I am trying to integrate a Velleman relay card [VM8090](https://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?id=382512) into my vb.net project. Unfortunately Velleman only provides a 32bit DLL, but our program is compiled x64. Therefore I try the communication directly over the serial interface (USB).

This is the protocol [description](https://ufile.io/vmbjt687) from Velleman.

Communication with the demo app provided by Velleman works perfectly. After setting a relaystate I get a response from the relay card. This is displayed in the demo app.

[image]

The crazy thing is: after opening the serial interface in vb.net I don’t get any traffic infos in the demo app (and vb.net also) anymore. But I need this relais-status-infos (51h). But even though no more data is sent from the card, I can still turn relays on and off.

This code already causes the card to stop sending info.

```
myComPort = New SerialPort("COM3") With {
  .BaudRate = 19200,
  .DataBits = 8,
  .Parity = Parity.None,
  .StopBits = 1,
  .Handshake = Handshake.None,
  .ReadBufferSize = 1024,
  .WriteBufferSize = 1024}
myComPort.Open()
myComPort.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that only 1 program uses the SerialPort, usually only 1 program can read and send data through a SerialPort.
  Also check if the device is connected to the correct usb port (usb port 3 in this case).
- Check if all SerialPort settings are set correctly
- Finally, in your code the comPort is opened and immediately closed again
  `myComPort.Open() myComPort.Close()`
  Only close the comPort when you want to close the program or the communication between your computer and the hardware.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I must note that the connection to the card works. I can send a command via the serial port and the corresponding relay turns on / off.
The problem is that as soon as I connect to the card (with the code above) from then on the card no longer sends a response.